# Porting Orange Book shaders to OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I am trying to port the Orange Book brick shader to OpenGL ES 2.0 and I am running into problems with the lighting.  With out the lighting I see the bricks, but with it the shape is just black.
[image][image]

**Vert**

```
const float ZERO = 0.0;
const float ONE = 1.0;

// Should be built in, but this is GLES
uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;
attribute vec4 Vertex;
attribute vec3 Normal;

// Other variables
uniform vec3 LightPosition;

const float SpecularContribution = 0.3;
const float DiffuseContribution = 1.0 - SpecularContribution;

varying float LightIntensity;
varying vec2 MCPosition;

void main()
{
    vec3 ecPosition = vec3(ModelViewMatrix * Vertex);
    vec3 tnorm      = normalize(NormalMatrix * Normal);
    vec3 lightVec   = normalize(LightPosition - ecPosition);
    vec3 reflectVec = reflect(-lightVec, tnorm);
    vec3 viewVec    = normalize(-ecPosition);
    float diffuse   = max(dot(lightVec, tnorm), ZERO);
    float spec      = ZERO;

        if(diffuse > ZERO)
    {
        spec = max(dot(reflectVec, viewVec), ZERO);
        spec = pow(spec, 16.0);
    }

    LightIntensity  = DiffuseContribution * diffuse +
              SpecularContribution * spec;

    MCPosition  = Vertex.xy;
    gl_Position = ModelViewProjectionMatrix * Vertex;
}
```

**Frag**

```
precision mediump float;

const float ONE = 1.0;
const float HALF = 0.5;

uniform vec3 BrickColor, MortarColor;
uniform vec2 BrickSize, BrickPercent;

varying float LightIntensity;
varying vec2 MCPosition;

void main()
{
    vec3 color;
    vec2 position, useBrick;

    position = MCPosition / BrickSize;

    if(fract(position.y * HALF) > HALF)
        position.x += HALF;

    position = fract(position);

    useBrick = step(position, BrickPercent);

    color = mix(MortarColor, BrickColor, useBrick.x * useBrick.y);
    color *= LightIntensity;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, ONE);
}
```

**Here's my Java**

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config)
{
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.3922f, 0.5843f, 0.9294f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    try
    {
        mTorus.genTorus(60, 1.25f, 0.5f);
        mAngle = 45.0f;

        mProgramObject = ESShader.loadProgram(mContext, "cube.vert", "cube.frag");

        mModelViewLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "ModelViewMatrix");
        mMVPLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "ModelViewProjectionMatrix");
        mNormalMatrixLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "NormalMatrix");
        mLightPositionLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "LightPosition");

        mBrickColorLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "BrickColor");
        mMortarColorLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "MortarColor");
        mBrickSizeLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "BrickSize");
        mBrickPercentLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "BrickPercent");

        mPositionLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramObject, "Vertex");
            mNormalLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramObject, "Normal");
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        System.err.println("Failed to load shaders");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height)
{
    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;

    mProjection.loadIdentity();
    mProjection.perspective(60.0f, (float)mWidth / (float)mHeight, 1.0f, 20.0f);

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
}

private void update()
{
    if(mLastTime == 0) mLastTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long curTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = curTime - mLastTime;
    float deltaTime = elapsedTime / 1000.0f;
    mLastTime = curTime;

    // Compute a rotation angle based on time to rotate the cube
    mAngle += (deltaTime * 40.0f);
    if(mAngle >= 360.0f) mAngle -= 360.0f;
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused)
{
    update();
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Use the program object
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramObject);

    mModelView.loadIdentity();
    mModelView.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
    mModelView.rotate(mAngle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.75f);

    mNormalMatrix.load(mModelView);
    mNormalMatrix.invert();
    mNormalMatrix.transpose();

    mMVPMatrix.multiply(mModelView, mProjection);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mModelViewLoc, 1, false, mModelView.getAsFloatBuffer());
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPLoc, 1, false, mMVPMatrix.getAsFloatBuffer());
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mNormalMatrixLoc, 1, false, mNormalMatrix.getAsFloatBuffer());
    GLES20.glUniform3f(mLightPositionLoc, 5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);

    GLES20.glUniform3f(mBrickColorLoc, 0.549f, 0.239f, 0.271f);
    GLES20.glUniform3f(mMortarColorLoc, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);
    GLES20.glUniform2f(mBrickSizeLoc, 0.3f, 0.15f);
    GLES20.glUniform2f(mBrickPercentLoc, 0.9f, 0.85f);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionLoc, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mTorus.getVertices());
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionLoc);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mNormalLoc, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mTorus.getNormals());
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mNormalLoc);

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, mTorus.getNumIndices(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mTorus.getIndices());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was passing in the wrong values for my NormalMatrix.  The NormalMatrix is the Upper-Left 3x3 of the Transpose of the Inverse of the ModelViewMatrix.  For that I had this code:

```
mNormalMatrix.load(mModelView);
mNormalMatrix.invert();
mNormalMatrix.transpose();
```

Which resulted in a 4x4 Matrix, but in my shader I had it as a mat3, this shifted the values around and made it fail.